# define extern variable inside a function

Tags: c, extern

Lets say I have an `extern` function pointer in a header file

```
extern void (__stdcall * const glEnable) (GLenum cap);
```

is there a way to define it inside a function, because its definition depends on other stuff

```
void glInit()
{
    ...
    Lib lib = loadLib("opengl");
    glEnable = procAddr(lib, "glEnable");
    ...
}
```

Comment: `to define it inside a function` No it is not possible - symbols declared at file scope have to be defined at file scope. I do not believe such an answer solves your _real underlying_ problem in any way... are you asking an XY question?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference of declaring, defining and initialising a variable?

Comment: It's unclear what initialization needs to be done on a function pointer. Could you show us how you'd like this to work so we can see the "other stuff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// .h file
extern void (__stdcall * glEnable) (GLenum cap);


// .c file
void (__stdcall * glEnable) (GLenum cap) = NULL;

void glInit()
{
    Lib lib = loadLib("opengl");
    glEnable = procAddr(lib, "glEnable");
}
```

Now, the function pointer is null until someone calls `glInit`. It is undefined behavior to call that function pointer before calling `glInit`, and I assume that was your intention anyway.